# Machine that can turn phone 90 degrees every few seconds?

Tags: android

I want to detect memory leaks in my Android application. Some leaks could be detected while rotating the phone physically so that the activities are constantly recreated.

I'm looking of some sort of physical device that could turn the phone 90 degrees every X seconds. I could build something using lego Mindstorm (that would actually be very cool), but I'm looking for something cheaper.

I also thought of using a clock, but I couldn't find one that has a clock second hand strong enough. Futhermore if the phone rotate 360 degrees after some time the USB cable would become too twisted. I think a device that goes back and forth between horizontal and vertical would be perfect.

My dream testing machine would also allow me to plug a USB cable so that I can run the Monkey tool while constantly rotating the phone.

Comment: You could use an intern. On a serious note, if you have Knex + a motor, it might be fairly simple (and/or cheap) to build something!

Comment: Put the phone on a drill (diy adapter or pro-solution: duct tape) and let it go on low revs... =D

Comment: +1 for a way cool question :-)

Comment: If you're checking *your application* for leaks (instead of questioning a certain physical phone) why would you not just do this through the emulator?

Comment: Ditto on the Mindstorms, or perhaps some Arduino? Google released an Android version to build apps for Arduino at the last IO, of course these are all DYI, for some of us that's a benefit. ;)

Comment: @Hostile Fork: This is done in the QA phase, which dictate that real phones should be used (the emulator doesn't have SenseUI for example)

Comment: In the States, we have an expression "using a Buick to swat a fly". That came to mind reading your description. IMHO, you will spend vastly more time trying to engineer this solution than it will take for you to either do it in software or simply flick your wrist lots of times. I mean, if you're looking to do this because you like tinkering with this sort of steampunk solution, go ahead, but I don't like the implication that Android development requires mechanical aids.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to trigger configuration change somehow. This might be orientation change, hardware keyboard is opened or hidden, or any other change listed here: [`android:configChanges`](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#config).

And there is one way to change configuration without using physical approach. You can use "Car Mode" or "Night Mode". Both only work in Android 8+ and can be turned on/off using [`UiModeManager`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/UiModeManager.html#enableCarMode%28int%29).

So you can write your custom Service that will periodically call `UiModeManager.enableCarMode(0)` and `UiModeManager.disableCarMode(0);`, which in turn will force configuration changes in your Activity under test.

Answer (score 5):

Why don't you just force the orientation change or destroy and recreate the views every X seconds? I think it's more reliable than a mechanical approach. I can also recommend you this : http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/monkey.html

Comment: Or write a test suite, since that destroys and recreates activities with each test method. Ideally MonkeyRunner would be an option, but I don't think you can rotate the screen with it currently.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps http://mindstorms.lego.com/  Lego MindStorms?  To be fair, it's about $250 so not really "throwaway cheap" but the advantage of being fully programmable might outweigh that.

As far as I know it's the cheapest robot kit out there which is why universities and schools use it.